# When I add gatsby-plugin-sass in gatsby-confis.js file

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
```

already add the plugin but still error

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>   Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Answer (score 1):

Nose Sass isn’t included with the plugin, so also try running:

```
npm install -S node-sass
```

Per: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sass/#install

That way for most changes you can easily upgrade or change versions of Node Sass, without needing to wait on a change from the Gatsby plugin maintainers.

Hope that helps!